# Add four spaces before each line of code in terminal [Windows]

Tags: bash, text-processing

Is there any faster way to add fours spaces to each line except by manually adding it? How could it be done from a terminal in Windows?

```
sed 's/^/    /' file
```

This would work on unix/linux.
How could this command be written in Windows?

- I get this error:

  'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

Comment: With sed for Windows? Same, just use double quotes

Comment: *"'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command"* - of course, install it first.

Comment: sorry, I don't know anything about bash and text-processing, could you briefly explain me after I install it, how to use it in terminal, after installing I get same error

Comment: What bash implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `sed` is not recognised, you won't be able to use it, so you need to install it first, as already mentioned by Wiktor.

In order to do this, there are two typical ways:

- Install Cygwin, this contains a list of UNIX/Linux-like programs which you can use as commandline programs.
- Install a Windows subsystem for Linux. Once you have that, you can run every UNIX/Linux-like program, using `wsl <command>`, as you can see in this example:

  ```
  Windows command prompt>wsl sed
  Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...
  ```

Comment: I installed cygwin but I get same error, I tried to install wsl with `wsl --install` and I get this error `The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.`

Comment: When you have installed Cygwin, then you should have `sed` as a program, so you don't need to preceed it by `wsl`, just type `sed`.